# Close kivy popup from another class

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am writing a simple Vocabulary App and when the user submits an answer, a popup should display if he has answered correct or not. This works so far, but when the popup should be dismissed/closed the app crashes telling that `AttributeError: 'MyScreenManager' object has no attribute 'close_pop'`
which does makes sense, because the close_pop method is defined in the PopupWindow class (I'd like to separate the different concerns if possible)

I though of two possible solutions, but don't know how to realize them:

1: Call the close_pop method from within the MyScreenManager class, but I don't know how to reference the popup object that should be closed

2: Adjust the kv part:

```
<PopupWindow>:
    pLabel: pLabel

    Label:
        id: pLabel
        size_hint: .6, .2
        pos_hint:{'x': .2, 'top': 1}
        font_name: 'static/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf'
    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        size_hint: .8, .2
        pos_hint:{'x': .1, 'y': .1}
        on_release: app.root.close_pop()
```

to not call the root class (MyScreenManager), but instead do something like `app.PopupWindow.close_pop()`, but this doesn't work either.

I was able to get it working without screenmanager (and putting all methods into one class 'Mainwindow' which also was the root class then) but for further enhancements I'd like to use screen manager :)

Any other fine solution will also work - thanks a lot!

Here is my Python Code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import unidecode

from kivy.app import App
#from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
#from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
#from kivy.uix.actionbar import ActionBar
#from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class MainWindow(Screen):
    userInput = ObjectProperty(None)
    vocab = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.df = pd.read_excel(r"static/HSK1-Vocabulary-List.xlsx")
        self.en = self.df['English']
        self.zh = self.df['Chinese']
        self.pinyin = self.df['Pinyin']
        self.rd = None

    def btn_submit(self):
        if self.rd is None:
            pLabel = "Please start before submitting!"
        elif not self.userInput.text:
            pLabel = "Please enter something!"
        else:
            pLabel = self.validate(self.userInput.text)
            self.btn_next()
        PopupWindow(pLabel).open_popup()

    def btn_next(self):
        self.userInput.text = ""
        self.rd = random.randint(0, self.df.shape[0]-1)
        self.vocab.text = "What is '{}' in Chinese?".format(self.en[self.rd])

    def validate(self, answer):
        def replace_tones(orig_voc):
            unaccented_voc = unidecode.unidecode(orig_voc)
            return(unaccented_voc)

        if answer == self.zh[self.rd]:
            #correct+=1
            return("Well done, even in chinese characters!")
        elif answer == self.pinyin[self.rd]:
            #correct+=1
            return("Well done, you also got the correct tones!")
        elif answer == replace_tones(self.pinyin[self.rd]):
            #correct+=1
            return("Well done! Keep in mind the tones '{}'".format(self.pinyin[self.rd]))
        else:
            return("Sorry, that was not correct!\nThe correct vocab is {}".format(self.pinyin[self.rd]))
        #cnt+=1


class PopupWindow(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, userInput):
        super().__init__()
        self.pLabel.text = userInput

    def open_popup(self):
        content = PopupWindow(self.pLabel.text)
        self.pop = Popup(title="Result", content=content, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        self.pop.open()

    def close_pop(self):
        self.pop.dismiss()


class DashboardWindow(Screen):
    pass    


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass
    #def close_pop(self):
    #    print("This should close the popup...")


KV = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class VocabularyTrainer(App):
    def build(self):
        return KV


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = VocabularyTrainer()
    app.run()
```

and here my .kv file:

```
MyScreenManager:
    MainWindow:
    DashboardWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'
    vocab: vocab
    userInput: userInput

    GridLayout:
        size: root.width, root.height
        rows: 4

        ActionBar:
            id: actBar
            background_image: ''
            background_color: (0.53, 0.808, 0.98, 1)

            ActionView:
                ActionPrevious:
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Quiz'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Training'
                ActionButton:
                    text: 'Settings'

        Label:
            id: vocab
            text: 'Welcome to the Chinese Learning App!'

        TextInput:
            id: userInput
            hint_text: 'Enter answer'
            width: 300
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.btn_submit()
            font_name: 'static/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            Button:
                text: 'Submit'
                on_press: root.btn_submit()
            Button:
                text: 'Start/Skip'
                on_press: root.btn_next()
            Button:
                text: 'Dashboard'
                on_press: app.root.current = 'dashboard'

<PopupWindow>:
    pLabel: pLabel

    Label:
        id: pLabel
        size_hint: .6, .2
        pos_hint:{'x': .2, 'top': 1}
        font_name: 'static/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf'
    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        size_hint: .8, .2
        pos_hint:{'x': .1, 'y': .1}
        on_release: app.root.close_pop()

<DashboardWindow>:
    name: 'dashboard'
    GridLayout:
        rows: 2
        Label:
            text: '<e.g. PieChart Results>'
        Button:
            text: 'Go back'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `PopupWindow` is creating two `PopupWindows` each time you use it. A better approach would be to just create one, like this:

```
class PopupWindow(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, userInput):
        super().__init__()
        self.pLabel.text = userInput
        self.pop = Popup(title="Result", content=self, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    def open_popup(self):
        self.pop.open()

    def close_pop(self):
        self.pop.dismiss()
```

Then in your `kv` you can use:

```
<PopupWindow>:
    pLabel: pLabel

    Label:
        id: pLabel
        size_hint: .6, .2
        pos_hint:{'x': .2, 'top': 1}
        font_name: 'static/NotoSansSC-Regular.otf'
    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        size_hint: .8, .2
        pos_hint:{'x': .1, 'y': .1}
        on_release: root.close_pop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the logic I tried to implement although MisterNox solution also looks interesting!
Could you explain (or both of you) explain if there is a "more preferred" one?

Answer (score 1):

You should break it down to a simple example of your problem. From what I have seen so far you should try to change your btn_submit method to something like this to make the popup accessible easily:

```
def btn_submit(self):
    if self.rd is None:
        pLabel = "Please start before submitting!"
    elif not self.userInput.text:
        pLabel = "Please enter something!"
    else:
        pLabel = self.validate(self.userInput.text)
        self.btn_next()
    self.mypopup = PopupWindow(pLabel)
    self.mypopup.open_popup()
```

and then you should be able to access it with your screenmanager like this:

```
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

   def close_pop(self):
        print("This should close the popup...")
        self.get_screen('main').mypopup.close_pop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! This works as well, but I'm wondering if this is "best practice" because I saw examples where the screen manager class was left empty and the logic basically was implemented in the other classes.
But of course I asked for it, so thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course, there are more ways of doing it. What should trigger the popup to dismiss? You can do it from your screen, from a button, you are completely free. I just made this example as you asked for a solution with the screen manager.

Comment: just saw the solution from John Anderson. Thats a good one, you should go with it.